Algebras with an extension-contraction property.
If $A\to B$ is a faithfully flat ring map then for any ideal $I\trianglelefteq A$ you have that $A\cap IB = I$. Say that a ring map $A\to B$ satisfies the extension-contraction property if this latter condition holds.
If $B$ is flat and satisfies the extension-contraction property then $B$ is faithfully flat as easily seen by the characterization of faithfully flat algebras as ones in which $\mathfrak{p}B\neq B$ for all prime ideals of $A$.
Can one characterize maps with the extension-contraction property in the absence of any flatness assumption? While curious in the general case, I am also fine with answers enforcing some finiteness conditions on $A$ or $B$.

The condition is way too broad / weak. Maybe you want to ask something more specific, and show the context where this popped up?

There is no context in which it showed up other than curiosity about if this is a condition that has been studied. As I noted it's true for faithfully flat maps and can be seen to be equivalent with flatness and I simply wondered if there's any other characterization of them.
